# Is there a Within Formula somewhere?

Tags: function, google-sheets, search, find

I am trying to determine if there is a specific string of data in a cell. so if have a cell that says 1 2 3 4 5 6. Using the Space as a delimiter. is there a way for me to query the 4 out of it? and get a return of the 4?

I have tried using search and find but thats are just giving me the len position within the cell.

Comment: Do be aware that adding both the tags #excel and #google-sheets to a question is liable to get you wrong answers since their functions and syntax sometimes differ greatly

Comment: you can use "MID to pull a substring out of another string if you know the length of the substring.

Answer (score 1):

So, use find(), which you say you did but did not show how...

What about:

```
=if(iferror(find(A1,B1,1),0)>0,A1,"Not found")
```

[image]

Comment: My problem with find is it would keep erroring out. On the sheet itself I would do a find on the column itself. and only get back a specific cell that wouldnt even hold the data i wanted it to search through in the first place.

Comment: @lylerachir which is why I used iferror()…

Answer (score 0):

I've setup my sheet like so:

[image: An excel sheet with the numbers "1 2 3 4 5 6" in cell A2, the number 4 in cell B2, and the formula `MID(A2,SEARCH("4",A2,1)) in cell B1]

The formula works like so:

```
mid(A2,                  //grab a substring from the middle of A2
       SEARCH("4",A2)    //find the value "4" inside A2
                     ,1) //make MID grab exactly one character (length of string "4"
```

With some jimmying, you can generalize this however you want.

Comment: Using this formula would it also work if i ended up needing the 1 or the 6 as well?

Comment: Yes but do be aware that the formula is looking for literal text within the string. If you just want to know whether the text exists, you could use find and IFERROR to handle if the text doesn't exist.

Comment: oh i need the exact text within the string. so this should get me pointed in the path i need the rest of the way thank you.

Comment: If you want to see find() and iferror() applied - check out my answer. @lylerachir

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1&""; "\b4")
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution for Google Sheets:

```
=if(iserror(MATCH(A1,SPLIT(B1," "),0)),"",A1)
```

(aka: look for A1 in B1)
enjoy